# RDF/OWL/Protege: let a subclass be a union of some disjoint super classes?

Tags: class, properties, union, owl, protege

I have following classes: Classes B, C and D are the subclasses of A.

```
A ----+----------> B
      |
      +----------> C
      |
      +----------> D
```

Besides, I have an object property, *hasObjectProperty*, and some other classes X, Y, Z,
**where X, Y, Z are disjoint classes**.

Then I set restrictions to classes B, C and D as following:
(Here I use Manchester OWL syntax used in Protege as well http://www.co-ode.org/resources/reference/manchester_syntax/ )

```
B: (hasObjectProperty only X) and (hasObjectProperty some X)
C: (hasObjectProperty only Y) and (hasObjectProperty some Y)
D: (hasObjectProperty only Z) and (hasObjectProperty some Z)
```

now the question is, how can I describe a Class E, which should be the union of only Class B and C?
How can I describe a Class which can be both Class B and Class C (but not Class D)?

```
A ----+----------> B ------> E
      |
      +----------> C ------> E
      |
      +----------> D
```

is is possible?

I tried to define Class E's restriction like this. But a Reasoner will determine it as invalid.

```
E: ((hasObjectProperty only X) and (hasObjectProperty some X)) or ((hasObjectProperty only Y) and (hasObjectProperty some Y))
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid"? Unsatisfiable?

Comment: Why do you think that *hasObjectProperty* has any relevance to your problem (i.e. describing a union)?

Comment: The reasoner treats such ontology invalid. Since it come to the result that X must be Y (however X and Y are disjoint)

Answer (score 3):

In order to restrict `E` to be exactly the union of `B` and `C`, you can state:

`E` ≡ (`B` or `C`)

i.e., that anything belonging to the *union* of `B` and `C` is in `E`, and vice-versa (encoding the subsumption relationship both ways).

Note that this necessarily makes `E` a superclass to both `B` and `C` since it contains them both, so you will instead get:

```
A --+---> E --+---> B
    |         | 
    +---> D   +---> C
```